# Is Red Bull™ kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Is the Red Bull™ energy drink kosher?

Comment: Future readers should be aware that the Red Bull's status as kosher may change over time.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean it's good for you.

Comment: If it is available internationally it may vary from one place to another dependent on what else is processed in the factory, assuming all its ingredients are kosher and that they don't vary from one location to another.

Answer (score 9):

According to the Chicago Rabbinical Council (cRc), the "Original Energy Drinks" in regular and diet are kosher while the "Cola" and "Shots" are not: [cRc Kosher Beverage List.](http://www.crcweb.org/beverage_list.php)

Comment: Both answers are correct.  The cRC compiles a list of recommended beverages, not all of which it certifies itself.  The actual certification comes from London's Federation which is a well-recognized hashgacha (their hechsher symbol is an octagon with KF in it).  Most people in America haven't heard of that hechsher, but will readily follow the cRC and Star-K's endorsement of this product.

Comment: Personally, I couldn't care less if it's got a proper hechsher or not. I tried Red Bull once, and it was disgusting! Give me good ol' coffee any day of the week!

Answer (score 3):

Hashgacha/Supervision: Beth Din of the Federation of Synagogues London

Answer (score 1):

Rav Abadi also holds that Red Bull is Kosher.

See: [Kashrut.org](http://www.kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=14525&highlight=red%20bull)